# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows ... when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-update, inner-join, where-clause, exists

I looked over the other answers, but none of them answered what I am doing wrong or I don't get it.

I am trying to update a table from another table, but they don't share a common reference. A third table does share a reference with both of theses tables, so how do I get them to reference each other to do the update. Here is my best attempt.

```
Update jobs

Set Phone = (Select coalesce([Work Phone], [Home Phone], [Cell Phone]) 
            from Contacts c  
                INNER JOIN Easement_Contacts e on c.CPID = e.Contact_ID)

Where Exists (Select Contact_ID 
              from Easement_Contacts e 
                  INNER JOIN Jobs j on j.Easement = e.Easement_ID)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
UPDATE j
SET Phone = coalesce(c.[Work Phone], c.[Home Phone], c.[Cell Phone])
FROM jobs j
    JOIN Easement_Contacts e on j.Easement = e.Easement_ID
    JOIN Contacts c on e.Contact_ID = c.CPID
```

I am assuming all 3 of the phone numbers are coming form the contacts table in your example.  The correlated subquery you were trying to use was not anchored to the "jobs" table since it didn't contain a join or where clause that referenced an object outside the scope of the subquery.  By referencing the table you want to update in a FROM clause, you can join all your tables and set the context of the UPDATE statement by using the "jobs" alias as the subject of the UPDATE statement at the top.

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo, and you are right to bring up the m:n relation.  I was taking for granted the model was keyed properly.  But multiple row matches could make that update non-deterministic.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I was hung up on keeping the Contacts table in the select statement.

Comment: Why is the FROM on Jobs and not Contacts since the data is coming from Contacts? I am assuming that with the JOIN order doesn't matter it's about the whole set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your tables structure it is a bit like reading in the magic glass bulb. This question might be a good example for an *updateable CTE*. But be aware, that with a *m:n-relation* the same row might get updated with a fairly random value...

I'd suggest first do take the CTE's `SELECT` isolated (add the columns you need to control the output and check, whether the right `NewPhone` sits beside the `Phone`, which should be updated.

Finally you run  a query like this:

```
WITH myCTE AS
(
    SELECT j.Phone
          ,coalesce(c.[Work Phone], c.[Home Phone], c.[Cell Phone],'Some dummy?') AS NewPhone
    FROM jobs AS j
    INNER JOIN Easment_Contacts AS e ON j.Easment=e.Easment_ID
    INNER JOIN Contacts As c ON e.Contact_ID=c.CPID
)
UPDATE myCTE SET Phone=NewPhone
```